# How to display Users V/s Response Graphs on jenkins of Jmeter result

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

Is there a way to display users v/s response graph on jenkins from jmeter result ? 
or which graph displays User v/s Response through jmeter result ? As below

```
      |
         |
         |
Response |
         |
         |_____________________
               Users
```

Answer (score 0):

[Response Time vs Threads](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ResponseTimesVsThreads/) chart seems to be something you're looking for.

[image: JMeter Plugins Response Time vs Threads]

When it comes to JMeter test execution in Jenkins you can use [Graphs Generator Listener](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/GraphsGeneratorListener/) to automatically generate the chart after your test is finished, once done you can a[rchive generated .png file(s)](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/examples/#archive-build-output-artifacts) so the chart will be added to your build dashboard.

You can install Response Time vs Threads and Graphs Generator Listener using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager)

Comment: yes but i am getting dotted graph instead Line graph

Comment: @Ashu123 Settings -> Graph Options -> Line width - set more than 1 to get the lines bolder

Comment: @user7294900 jmeter 4.0 has no Graph Options -> Line width.